# Spark aggregate keys from JSON input files and output values to a new JSON file

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, aggregation

I have JSON files that have the below structure in a directory.

```
{
 {
  "cts":1456877408861,
  "ts":1456877408861,
  "spn":"rootspan"
 },
 {
  "cts":1456877408862,
  "ts":1456877408862,
  "spn":"lowspan"
 }
}
```

I want to get an output like below using Spark Scala in a new file. How can I achieve that?

```
{
 "cts":2,
 "ts":2,
 "spn":2
}
```

This is what I tried.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Argos Aggregator")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
setHadoopConfiguration(sc)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc) 
val logData = sc.sequenceFile(inputFilePath, classOf[LongWritable], classOf[BytesWritable])
val rawJsonStringMap = logData.map{case (k,v) => (new String(v.copyBytes()))}
//jsonmap has json structure that i gave above
val jsonMap = sqlContext.read.json(rawJsonStringMap)
val schema = jsonMap.dtypes
jsonMap.show()
for (s <- schema) {
    val colName = s._1
    var rawColCount = jsonMap.select(colName).count()
    println("type = "+colName+ " Count = " + rawColCount)
}
```

Comment: Tell us, did you try anything so we can have a start point?

Comment: Just updated the main post.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, the json you have provided is not valid. It should be
>   something like this.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "cts": 1456877408861,
      "ts": 1456877408861,
      "spn": "rootspan"
    },
    {
      "cts": 1456877408862,
      "ts": 1456877408862,
      "spn": "lowspan"
    }
  ]
}
```

> You can write a udf to iterate over each object in the json array and
>   set counters for each fields.

```
def countData = udf((inputData:Seq[Row]) =>{
        var ctsCount = 0
        var tsCount = 0
        var spnCount = 0
        inputData.foreach(line => {
        if(line.getAs[String](0) != null)  ctsCount += 1
          if(line.getAs[String](1) != null) tsCount += 1
          if(line.getAs[String](2) != null) spnCount += 1
        })
        Map("cts" -> ctsCount,"ts" -> tsCount,"spn" -> spnCount)
      })
```

> You can call the udf after reading your json file.

```
val input = sqlContext.read.json("test.json")
val finalData = input.withColumn("output",countData(input("data"))).drop("data")
finalData.toJSON.foreach(println)
```

> Final Output:
>   {"output":{"cts":2,"ts":2,"spn":2}}